# Netbeans IDE version 8.0.1 is too slow

Tags: php, ide, netbeans-8

[I Want some plugins to keep remain in this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24lUG.png)My Netbeans IDE version 8.0.1 is too slow

I'm running netbeans on a Win8 32bit
I'm working on PHP+HTML+Js
I don't Use Java

When I use Netbeans And Chrome for About 1hr, It Will Shows Not Responding...

I think I Had Too Many unwanted Plugins....

How do I Restore to Default

Is there any configuration needed???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]To uninstall unwanted plugins .

Go to tools > plugins >Installed > select the (**user installed plugins**)-unwanted plugins  > Uninstall .

restart Netbeans .

if you don't know which are the default plugins in NetBeans . you can see in image below.[image]

Comment: @Rkoasmia It prompts me to uninstall All my user installed plugins... I need some plugins to keep remain in the list???.... I attach Image in my edited question pls refer

Comment: @Rahul : there is one checkbox named "show details" in Installed tab.  i've added image in my ans please . one you check that show details . you will be able to remove unwanted plugins .

Comment: Thanks Yaar it help me out